# Perl: Loop through a file and substitute

Tags: perl, file, substitution

I simply wanna read in a logfile, do a search and replace, and then write out the changes to that same logfile.

What's the best practice way of doing this in Perl?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I normally code up a one liner for this:

```
perl -i -pe 's/some/thing/' log.file
```

See [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100612201232/http://sial.org/howto/perl/one-liner/)

Comment: But why can't I use backreferances? Like perl -pi -e "s/foo(.*)bar/bar$1foo/" tezt2 doesn't work..

Comment: Your shell is probably corrupting the string. Try replacing your ""s with ''s so that the * doesn't get expanded.

Comment: While strict is usually pointless for oneliners, enabling warnings with -w will occasionally catch problems for you; you should do it habitually.

Answer (score 8):

This is often done with a one-liner:

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/find/replace/g" <file>
```

Note the `-i.bak` portion -- this creates a backup file with the extension `.bak`. If you want to play without a net you can do this to overwrite the existing file without a backup:

```
perl -pi -e "s/find/replace/g" <file>
```

Answer (score 2):

or you can use `sed` (I know... you asked about perl):

```
sed -i 's/find/replace/g' <file>
```

Comment: The way sed handles regular expression rules are...different, than Perl's, to say the least.