# Replace HTML text with a routine

Tags: html, perl, shell

I need a perl/shell script which will replace all the occurences of below HTML code within all the files with text:

```
<? test_routine ?>
```

HTML code

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <label>testlabel</label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This HTML code can occur with any number of spaces i.e

```
<tr><td><label>testlabel</label></td></tr>
```

is also a valid search criteria (i.e ignore all the spaces)

Can any one please let me know how i can resolve this using perl/shell script. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiline search replace with Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030787/multiline-search-replace-with-perl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one line of perl that will do what you need using a regular expression:

```
$html =~ s/<\s*tr\s*>\s*<\s*td\s*>\s*<\s*label\s*>\s*testlabel\s*<\s*\/label\s*>\s*<\s*\/td\s*>\s*<\s*\/tr\s*>/<? test_routine ?>/gi
```

Comment: On order to handle matches spanning multiple lines, wrap this in a script which reads the entire file at once, and add a /m modifier to the substitution.

    perl -0777 -pe 's%from%to%mg'

Comment: Actually, the `/m` modifer isn't needed in this case. You're right, though, the whole file has to be read into the `$html` variable before this line is run.

Comment: I printed $html and I'm able see the replaced text. Thanks for that. But how to write this back to the file?. I tried with open outfile, ">test.html";print (outfile "$html");

Comment: That depends. Could you give a bit more details on how the file is loaded?

Comment: my $file = "test.html"; my $a1 = do {local $/ = undef; open my $html, "<", $file; <$a1>}; close $a1;...followed with your statement above...and with my statement above..

Comment: If I've understood correctly an `test.html` is simply a file on your server, then you can overwrite it with `file_put_contents('test.html', $html);`.

Comment: I guess its php routine. I'm looking for perl solution

Comment: Ah, whoops, my bad. Thought it was PHP. This should do it in perl: `open FILE, ">test.html" or die $!; print FILE $html; close FILE;`

Comment: what if the file test.html is Readonly?

Comment: Umm.. There's really nothing you can do to change the contents of it then. Your only option would be writing to a different (new?) file which you have write access for. For example: open FILE, ">test2.html" or die $!; print FILE $html; close FILE;