# Replace Google Analytics code in a few hundred static pages?

Tags: bash, replace, sed, awk

I was hoping to create a bash script and use sed to replace old google analytics code with new but haven't had any success yet, currently getting "unterminated substitute pattern" errors when using the below code. Also I'm not sure I can use sed to replace blocks of text on multiple lines like this, maybe I have to use awk?

```
OLDANALYTICS='<script type=\"text/javascript\">
var gaJsHost = ((\"https:\" == document.location.protocol) ? \"https://ssl.\" : \"http://www.\");
document.write(unescape(\"%3Cscript src='\''\" + gaJsHost + \"google-analytics.com/ga.js'\'' type='\''text/javascript'\''%3E%3C/script%3E\"));
</script>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker(\"UA-111111-5\");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}</script>'

NEWANALYTICS='<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['\''_setAccount'\'', '\''UA-111111-5'\'']);
            _gaq.push(['\''_trackPageview'\'']);

            (function() {
                var ga = document.createElement('\''script'\''); ga.type = '\''text/javascript'\''; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('\''https:'\'' == document.location.protocol ? '\''https://ssl'\'' : '\''http://www'\'') + '\''.google-analytics.com/ga.js'\'';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('\''script'\'')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();

        </script>'

sed -i '' "s#$OLDANALYTICS#$NEWANALYTICS#g" $1
```

I'll have to incorporate this with a 'find' command once it is working, to replace text in all files recursively.

Comment: How did you generate these static pages?

Comment: They were created via an old employee's script, since lost, several years ago

Comment: Sed cannot match multi-line parterns without significant additional effort. I'd advise to move to Perl instead. But this is a very common FAQ; search this site for old questions about multi-line substitution.

Comment: You may want to look at [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030787/multiline-search-replace-with-perl) `perl` solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You may use TextPad to do search and replace in multiple files. It supports multi-line search and regular expression and is GUI. Also, it's a free software.

http://www.textpad.com/download/

Comment: The tags and question content suggest the user is on Linux/UNIX; TextPad is available only for Windows. Further, the question specifically asked about doing the task in a Bash script; not a GUI program to do it.

Comment: Just suggest another way of getting the job done. I guess it's not too hard to copy the files to a windows machine, process them and copy them back.