# Perl Regex Search and Replace Not Matching

Tags: regex, perl, search

I am trying to use perl to search and replace some outdated MySQL commands

```
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/if @RequestID.*@NextValue=@TableNameID output/if @RequestID is not NULL\n                begin\n                        select @TableNameID = @TableNameID + 1/smgi' $file1
```

However currently the file remains exactly the same before and after implying the regex isn't matching?

I have the flags `smgi` turned on so `.*` also matches new lines taking advice from [Multiline search replace with Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030787/multiline-search-replace-with-perl)

Here is a snip of the file I am trying to match

```
        if ( @@rowcount = 0 )
                return 1

        update Sequence set CurrentValue = @TableNameID where Code = 'TableName'
end

/* TableNames - Approval Request ID */
if @RequestID is not NULL
begin
        exec spGetNextSequence @Name='TableName', @NextValue=@TableNameID output

        insert into TableName        /* RequestID */
        (
                TableNameID,
                TxnVrsnID,
                FldNmCod,
```

If you test the pattern at http://regexpal.com/ (or any similar regex tester) - with `smi` on it matches fine?

Pattern: `if @ApprovalRequestID.*@NextValue=@TxnDecoratorID output`

---

This is the perl slightly split up so you can see what's going on

```
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/
if @RequestID.*@NextValue=@TableNameID output/
if @RequestID is not NULL\n
                begin\n
                        select @TableNameID = @TableNameID + 1
/smgi' $file1
```

Comment: This is why you use `-w` even with one-liners.

Comment: What does -w do? Edit: It produces warnings

Comment: It does indeed. In this case, it would have told you the problem right away: `Possible unintended interpolation of @RequestID in string at -e line 1.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@name` is interpolated as a named Perl array inside of regular expression patterns. Escape the `@` characters:

```
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/
if \@RequestID.*\@NextValue=\@TableNameID output/
if \@RequestID is not NULL\n
                begin\n
                        select \@TableNameID = \@TableNameID + 1
/smgi' $file1
```