# Replace two lines in a file with one new line with bash

Tags: bash, replace

I am trying to replace two lines in a file with one new line:

```
foo1.txt
  aaa   aaa
  bbb   bbb
  ccc   ccc
  ddd   ddd
  bbb   bbb
  ddd   ddd
```

after the replace the file should look like this

```
foo1.txt
  aaa   aaa
  eee   eee
  ddd   ddd
  bbb   bbb
  ddd   ddd
```

Is there a way with sed or some other command make this replace in all files of a folder

I have been trying with sed but without any success: `sed 's/bbb\tbbb\nccc\tccc/eee\teee/g' foo*.txt`

Comment: Do you want to replace a line with text ( of any string ) in all files in a folder with new line

Comment: Maybe this helps: [sed and Multi-Line Search and Replace](http://austinmatzko.com/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/)

Comment: I want to replace two lines with text ( with some special characters like tabs, dollar signs ) in all files in a folder with one new line

Comment: Updated the example file. The first line can be a lot of times in the files but it should be replaced only when the second line matches as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if this question should be already answered [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030787/multiline-search-replace-with-perl), I didn't manage to make the "one-line-one-command" solution work.

This command:

```
perl -pe 's/START.*STOP/replace_string/g' file_to_change
```

seems not to work for me and doesn't perform a multi-line replace. I had to split it in two different perl scripts, like this:

```
perl -pe 's/bbb\tbbb\n.*/placeholderstring/g' foo1.txt | perl -pe 's/placeholderstring  ccc\tccc/eee\teee/g'
```

Try to see what works best for you.

EDIT:

With the new sample text, the only solution that works is the one by [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell)

```
sed '/bbb\tbbb/{ N; s/.*ccc\tccc/  eee\teee/; }' foo1.txt
```

Comment: The second option does the trick, but I am left with some placeholderstring in the file... meaning that there are some lines that only match the first line and not the second... Will edit the example...

Comment: Maybe these two `perl` regexp are easier to remind, but I think that the solution provided by @William Pursell is the best one for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because the sed example as William described it was not so clear for me... In your answer I find it very clear and easy to adapt for my files! Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of ways to interpret your question.  If you are trying to replace lines at a fixed position, eg lines 2 and 3, do:

```
sed '2d; 3s/.*/newtext/'
```

If you want to replace a matching line and the line following:

```
sed '/pattern/{ N; s/.*/newtext/; }'
```

To replace the two consecutive lines in which the second line matches a pattern:

```
sed -n '$p; N; /pattern/d; P; D'
```

Comment: For the first, lines are not in a fixed position. For the second, it would be better if I could replace the line matching and the previous, not the following...

Comment: For the final example; `sed -n '$p; N; /pattern/d; P; D'`, obviously `pattern` is the pattern to match, but which part is the replacement string?

Comment: @Andy J There is no replacement string here.  This just deletes the two lines.  (oops!)  To do a replacement, you could do: `sed -n '$p; N; /pattern/s/.*/repl/; P; D'`

Answer (score 1):

```
nawk '{if($0~/bbb.*bbb/){getline;getline;print "newline"};print}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
aaa   aaa
bbb   bbb
ccc   ccc
ddd   ddd
> nawk '{if($0~/bbb.*bbb/){getline;getline;print "newline"};print}' temp
aaa   aaa
newline
ddd   ddd
```