# Perl script to search and replace multiple lines in multiple html files

Tags: regex, perl

I have many html files in a folder. I need to somehow remove a `<div id="user-info" ...>...</div>` from all of them. As far as I know I need to use a Perl script for that, but I don't know Perl to do that. Could someone get it for me?

Here is how the "bad" code looks like:

```
<div id="user-info" class="logged-in">
    <a class="icon icon-key-delete" href="https://test.dev/login.php?0,logout=1">Log Out</a>
    <a class="icon icon-user-edit" href="https://test.dev/control.php">Control Center</a>


</div> <!-- end of div id=user-info -->
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030787/multiline-search-replace-with-perl

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to figure that out. I did not have any PERL experience before.

Comment: Just a word of advice, we much prefer if you have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you, even if your attempt is completely broken. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`perl -0777 -i.withdiv -pe 's{<div[^>]+?id="user-info"[^>]*>.*?</div>}{}gsmi;' test.html`

`-0777` means split on nothing, so slurp in whole file (instead of line by line, the default for -p

`-i.withdiv` means alter files in place, leaving original with extension .withdiv (default for -p is to just print).

`-p` means pass line by line (except we are slurping) to passed code (see -e)

`-e` expects code to run.

`man perlrun` or `perldoc perlrun` for more info.

**Here's another solution**, which will be slightly more familiar to people that know jquery, as the syntax is *similar*.  This uses Mojolicious' `ojo` module to load up the html content into a Mojo::DOM object, transform it, and then print that transformed version:

`perl -Mojo -MFile::Slurp -E 'for (@ARGV) { say x(scalar(read_file $_))->at("#user-info")->replace("")->root; }' test.html test2.html test*.html`

To replace content directly:

`perl -Mojo -MFile::Slurp -E 'for (@ARGV) { write_file( $_, x(scalar(read_file $_))->at("#user-info")->replace("")->root ); }' test.html`

Note, this won't **JUST** remove the div, it will also re-write the content based on Mojo's Mojo::DOM module, so tag attributes may not be in the same order.  Specifically, I saw `<div id="user-info2" class="logged-in">` rewritten as `<div class="logged-in" id="user-info2">`.

Mojolicious requires at least perl 5.10, but after that there's no non-core requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please tell me how can I make a .pl file to do this?

Comment: @user1751343 Beware! If you have a `div` inside your `div id="user-info"` this will do funky things on your html.

Comment: That's very true.  Use at your own risk.  The other solution, using XML::XSH2 will give you more correct results in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
for { glob '*.html' } {
    open :F html (.) ;
    delete //div[@id="user-info" and @class="logged-in"] ;
    save :b ;
}
```