# Substring replacement using regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am having a terrible time with learning Perl regular expressions. I am trying to :

- Replace all occurrences of a single `#` at the beginning of a line with: `#####`.
- Replace all occurrences of a full line of `#` characters (ignoring leading or trailing spaces) with
  `# ---------- #`.

I know its `s/#` but that's all I know and all I can find. Any suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030787/multiline-search-replace-with-perl  I think you need to also define what is after the lines that already contains # is it followed by space or alphabet since what you do not want to do is replace those that already are ##### with duplicate #####

Answer (score 4):

The beginning of a line is matched by `^`. Therefore, a line starting with a `#` is matched by

```
/^#/
```

If you want the `#` to be single, i.e. not followed by another `#`, you must add a negative character class:

```
/^#[^#]/
```

We do not want to replace the character following the `#`, so we will replace it with a non matching group (called *negative look-ahead*):

```
/^#(?!#)/
```

To add the replacement, just change it to

```
s/^#(?!#)/#####/
```

The full line can be matched by the following regular expression:

```
/^#+$/
```

Plus means "once or more", `^` and `$` have already been explained. We just have to ignore the leading and trailing spaces (`*` means "zero or more"):

```
/^ *#+ *$/
```

We do not want the spaces to be replaced, so we have to keep them. Parentheses create "capture groups" that are numbered from 1:

```
s/^( *)#+( *)$/$1# ---------- #$2/
```

Comment: Don't you need to pick up the second character and add it to the replacement (or it will get replaced)? `s/^#([^#])|^#$/#####\1/`

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: Indeed. I started with look-ahead but removed it later to simplify things :) So back to the original version.

Comment: `/^#(?!#)/` is more correct for the first one than `/^#(?=[^#])/`

Answer (score 2):

For your first replacement:

```
$line =~ s/^#/#####/;
```

The idea here is that you want any line that *starts* with a '#'.  The '^' in the regex says that what follows must be at the beginning of the string.

And for your second replacement:

```
$line =~ s/^#+$/# ---------- #/;
```

This uses '^' again and '$'.  The '$' at the end says that what comes before must go to the end of the string.  '#+' says that there must be one or more '#' characters.  So, in other words, the entire string must consist of '#'.

Here's a test script and run:

```
$ cat foo.pl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines = (
        "foo line",
        "# single comment",
        "another line",
        "#############",
        "# line",
        "############",
);

foreach my $line( @lines ){
        print "ORIGINAL:  $line\n";
        $line =~ s/^#/#####/;
        $line =~ s/^#+$/# ---------- #/;
        print "NEW:       $line\n";
        print "\n";
}

$ ./foo.pl
ORIGINAL:  foo line
NEW:       foo line

ORIGINAL:  # single comment
NEW:       ##### single comment

ORIGINAL:  another line
NEW:       another line

ORIGINAL:  #############
NEW:       # ---------- #

ORIGINAL:  # line
NEW:       ##### line

ORIGINAL:  ############
NEW:       # ---------- #
```

Comment: Not sure if the assignment was supposed to be this hard, but `## Double comment` shouldn't be replaced if I understand the question correctly. If this is supposed to be a "comment beautifier" then the person writing the question might not have considered the possibility of line starting with two hashes.

Comment: true. i think i mentally distinguished "single comment" from "lone comment" when i answered.  oh natural language.  i think @choroba sufficiently covered what's necessary though.