# Conditionally comment html script statement across mulitple websites

Tags: html, regex, bash, scripting, conditional-statements

I have several websites each with multiple pages. Each of these pages has multiple scripts in them for various functions. There is a specific script that Im trying to comment out across all the sites.

The script I want to comment out has a target word I can use as a conditional to isolate it from the rest . I would like to use that word to target the script and wrap all of it (approx. 10 lines / including the `<script>` tags themselves) in a comment.

I have considered using regex, but it seems the multi-line and complex nature of script syntax may put this situation out of reach for a regex solution. Im not versed in regex, so I could be wrong.

Here is a rough idea of what needs to be commented out. What I want to keep are other similar script blocks without the conditional word (in this example "oranges.com"):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.__wtw_lucky_site_id = 15001;

(function() {
    var wa = document.createElement('script'); wa.type = 'text/javascript'; wa.async = true;
    wa.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://ww7632') + '.oranges.com/w.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(wa, s);
  })();
</script>
```

I suppose it would also be worth mentioning that I will be accessing and manipulating these files via ssh so preferably the solution would be compatible with that in some fashion.

Comment: You will possibly have better luck if you include representative samples of the scripts that need to be commented out and those which must be preserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with Perl (where the script you want to comment has `stuff` in it):

```
$ cat test.xml 
<html>
    <script>
        stuff
    </script>
    <script>
        other things
    </script>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
$ perl -0pe 's/<script([^>]*>.*?stuff.*?)<\/script>/<!-- script\1<\/script -->/smg' test.xml 
<html>
    <!-- script>
        stuff
    </script -->
    <script>
        other things
    </script>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

For reference, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1030819/1563512). This is a pretty quick and dirty solution. You could also write a script to essentially parse the XML with any number of libraries, loop over the elements, and modify the XML.

There may be an XSLT method, but I was not able to find one that looked particularly straight-forward.

Comment: This solution appears to have worked in the terminal output. When I open the file on the server it appears the changes do not commit. Is there something I have to do to write the changes to the file?

Comment: Yes, if you want to do it in place (to actually modify the file), add `-i` to the `perl` command line, e.g. `perl -i -0pe ...`.

Comment: Fantastic. _Exactly_ what I was after. Is there reasoning behind separating the -i flag from the -0pe?

Comment: There's no real reason to separate it -- you can try it both ways. Like most things, there's more than one way to do it. Generally, I don't like to do destructive things unless I'm really sure what I'm doing ;-) One approach would be to have a template and sometimes copy it to the real file and sometimes comment out the script part, but it depends on how complicated you want to be and how risk-averse you are.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `perl` solution on your files :

```
perl -0777 -p -e 's/(<script.*?orange.*?<\/script>)/\/\*\1\*\///s' file
```

The perl will match all multi-line patterns with the following format:

```
 <script ...
 ...
 </script>
```

It then checks to see if the word `orange` occurs on any of the lines within the matched pattern. If it does, the back reference `\1` replaces the matched pattern with itself, only difference is that `/*` is added at the start and `*/` is added at the end. So the output would look like:

```
/*<script ...
  ...
  </script>*/
```

**Alternatively**

You may also use a `python` script to achieve the same result:

```
import sys
import re

file = sys.argv[1]
f = open(file, 'r')
a = f.read() #read file into string
change = re.sub('(<script.*?orange.*?<\/script>)', r'/*\1*/', a, flags=re.DOTALL)  #flag DOTALL includes newline
print(change)
```

You can run the script as so:

```
python script.py file > newfile
cat newfile > file
```

This overwrites the contents of your file with the desired output.

Comment: I attempted to run the perl solution of your suggestion to no avail… Im not very experienced with perl to really debug myself. I do appreciate the effort. I ran the script and no changes were made even in the terminal output so Im assuming the script isnt picking up the condition properly.

Comment: use the python script, it should work without error, let me know if it works because I just tried it and it worked fine on my comp