# Insert a line in a specific pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to insert a line in a specific pattern that appears on several files, I first tried to do it with sed and then I realized that the perfect tools for this task will be perl.

So, I tried that (inspired from here [Multiline search replace with Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030787/multiline-search-replace-with-perl)):

```
perl -i.bak -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/(.*)markers:(.*)text:(.*)\n/$1markers:$2text:$3\nlink:/smg' myfile
```

On this file :

```
module_map:
  markers:
    - x: 1
    'y': 1
    text: "hello world"
    popup: true
    - x: 2
    'y': 2
    text: 'hello world'
    popup: false
```

to get that :

```
module_map:
  markers:
    - x: 1
    'y': 1
    text: "hello world"
    link:
    popup: true
    - x: 2
    'y': 2
    text: 'hello world'
    link:
    popup: false
```

(notice the "link:" line after the "text:" line)

I can't find any working solution. Do you have an idea ?
Thanks for reading :)

Comment: What do you know _for sure_ about the lines? Is it always going to say `text: ` and then some text? Is the text always surrounded by quotes? This will help future answers, as it will make the regex more specific and users more prepared.

Comment: Isn't it a YAML structure?

Comment: @Arc676 In fact, text can have any value : nothing, "", text_without_quotes, "text_with_quote"   
The only thing that is sure is that there is "text:" at the beginning of this line (and the indentation can change).   
Moreover, there are different lines beginning with "text:" in the file.

Comment: @choroba Yes this is YAML used by Jekyll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't try and do this all in one `regex`.

This is quite easy if you do:

```
 while ( <> ) { 
     print "   link:\n" if m/popup/;
     print;
 }
```

Which you can one-liner:

```
perl -pe 'print "   link:\n" if m/popup/;'
```

If you look at [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) or run this through `-MO=Deparse` what the `-p` flag does is wrap up your 'executable' stuff with:

```
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    print "   link:\n" if /popup/;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

Which means you can do WAY more than a simple `s///` pattern transform. You can even do this at the same time as using `-i` for inplace editing.

Note (as mentioned in comments) more about `m//` and `s///` can be found in [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) - `m/` denotes pattern match. It defaults to the current content of `$_` if you don't specify otherwise.

`s///` is a sed-style pattern replace. E.g. `s/replacethis/withthis/`. It also applies to `$_` by default.

If your logic is a bit more complicated than that (this will work fine on your sample data) it may be useful to think in terms of record separators - you can set `$/` to a record separator character, so you can process a chunk in one "go". You can see more about this in [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) - by default it's "linefeed" so you iterate a file one line at a time, but you can set it to any string value. (But note - not a regex). Or set it undefined, and then it'll read the whole file in one go.

E.g. in your above, you could set it to '-' and thus you would end up with:

```
local $/ = '-'; 

while ( <> ) {
    if ( m/text/ and m/popup/ ) {
        s/^(\s*popup)/    link:\n$1/m;
    }
    print; 
}
```

`/m` at the end of the regex (is also described in [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)) denotes 'span multiple lines'. This is needed because we're working with a multi-line chunk.

Comment: Thanks for your very good explanation ! There is just a few things I didn't understood in your last code : is the variable `$\ ` an implicit variable that automatically separate everything in block ? Can I put a string in it ? Do you have some link to this reference please ?
The second one is what does the `m/`, `\s` and `/m` things means ? Do you have some link to more explanation ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: $/ is the record separator. It defaults to line feed but can be any string. (but not a regex). See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html m/ is regex "match" and applies by default to the current record. (again, default current line, but because we set $/ it is the current chunk). s/ is sed style search and replace. /m is multi line. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html for more.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're trying to edit a YAML file. Why not to use a dedicated module?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use YAML;

my $s = << '---';
module_map:
  markers:
    - x: 1
      'y': 1
      text: "hello world"
      popup: true
    - x: 2
      'y': 2
      text: 'hello world'
      popup: false
---

my $href = Load($s);

for my $inner (@{ $href->{module_map}{markers} }) {
    $inner->{link} = undef if exists $inner->{text};
}

print Dump($href);
```

Note that I had to fix the indentation of the input data. In the output, you'll see

```
link: ~
```

I'm not sure you can get `link:` with no value (empty value roundtrips to `~` in both [YAML](http://p3rl.org/YAML) and [YAML::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/YAML::Tiny)).

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't see this that way ! But in my example, it would be more complicated because those files contains html in the other part of the file. So I would need to carry about that too.
`link:` with no value is allowed for the YAML used in Jekyll.