# perl oneliner substitutes anything after intended matching

Tags: perl, substitution

i have this file `test` (the amount of lines between the curly braces can vary a few lines):

```
\Email{test}
\Adresse{tes \\
test \\
test}
\Gruss{test}
```

what i want:

```
\Email{test}
\Adresse{}
\Gruss{test}
```

But the [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1030819/5124117)`perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/\\Adresse.*}/\\Adresse{}/smg' test`

converts the text to

```
\Email{}
\Adresse{}
\Gruss{}
```

and deletes the `\Gruss{test}`. How i can prevent this behavior?

**EDIT** to clarify: i want to keep the whole text after and before \Adresse{}. Additionally, i had some problems with one of the provided solutions on my "real file", so i improved my description of the problem.

Comment: So you want remove multiline and keep single line text between the `{}`?

Comment: i want to remove anything between those `{ }`

Comment: then EDIT your question - because you said for want: `\Gruss{test}`... :(

Comment: ah, sorry. i misunderstood you. I want anything in between the `\Adresse{}` to be removed. Anything else before `\Adresse{}` and after `\Adresse{}` should not be touched. so i want to keep`\Gruss{test}`

Comment: `echo -e "\\Adresse{tes\ntest\ntest}\n\\Gruss{test}" | perl -0777 -pe 's/\\Adresse\{\K[^}]*//g'`

Comment: @Miller this works also as expected. if you want, you can rewrite that as a answer, so that i can upvote it.

Comment: Are there ever going to be `\command{...}`s inside the Adresse argument?

Comment: @ysth nope. Why do you think so?

Comment: I don't think so; I was just asking because that would make the answer very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try

```
perl -0 -pe 's/(\\Adresse\{).*?}/$1}/sg'
```

from

```
\Adresse{tes
test
test}
\Gruss{test}
```

produces

```
\Adresse{}
\Gruss{test}
```

from

```
\Email{test}
\Adresse{tes \\
test \\
test}
\Gruss{test}
```

produces

```
\Email{test}
\Adresse{}
\Gruss{test}
```

Comment: could you additionally please  explain why my command does not work and yours does? is the non-greedy behavior standard in perl?

Comment: @toogley, every regex is greedy by default - e.g tries match the most of possible characters. Not only in perl. The `.*?` says - be non-greedy -  match the few possible characters - e.g. stop in the first found of the `}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using "non-greedy" match combined with `/s` regex modifier to match newlines with `.`. Also, you can replace `BEGIN{undef $/;}` with `-0` option:

```
perl -0 -pe 's/{.*?}/{}/sg' test
```

Comment: The greedy vs non-greedy aspect is correct, but why remove the match to `\\Adresse`? OP appears to want contents of other starting curly brackets to remain in place, just empty the `\\Adresse{}` ones. . .